# OpenCascade Undefined reference for function

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, opencascade

I'm just starting out with OpenCascade.  I decided to start with their example making a bottle:

https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/overview/html/occt__tutorial.html

I got as far as trying to make the arc with three points.  Here is my code

```
    #include <iostream>

#include <gp_Pnt.hxx>
#include <GC_MakeArcOfCircle.hxx>

void whatever() {
    double myWidth = 50.0;
    double myHeight = 70.0;
    double myThickness = 30.0;

    // Profile : Define Support Points
    gp_Pnt aPnt1(-myWidth / 2., 0, 0);
    gp_Pnt aPnt2(-myWidth / 2., -myThickness / 4., 0);
    gp_Pnt aPnt3(0, -myThickness / 2., 0);
    gp_Pnt aPnt4(myWidth / 2., -myThickness / 4., 0);
    gp_Pnt aPnt5(myWidth / 2., 0, 0);

    // Profile : Define the Geometry
    Handle(Geom_TrimmedCurve) anArcOfCircle = GC_MakeArcOfCircle(aPnt2,aPnt3,aPnt4);

}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    return 0; }
```

As you can see, it's really only the first few lines of the tutorial.  The line that makes the Arc crashes with the following error:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x179): undefined reference to `GC_MakeArcOfCircle::GC_MakeArcOfCircle(gp_Pnt const&, gp_Pnt const&, gp_Pnt const&)'
```

I'm not very experienced in C++, but it looks like it's not seeing the function GC_MakeArcOfCircle, but I'm really not sure why, since I've already determined that OpenCascase is working correctly.  Any help on figuring out what this means would be really helpful.

Comment: The class `GC_MakeArcOfCircle` is in the library `TKGeomBase.dll`. Are you linking that library?

Comment: I'm actually in Debian, so it would be TKGeomBase.so, but I bet that's what I'm missing.